# Merge objects of single array on basis of object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I'm confused to merge array contents from JavaScript.
Please help to get the best way to get desired result. A i also have tried other ways referred on SO.

```
[
    {
        "Afghanistan": 2646432,
        "categories": "2018"
    },
    {
        "Afghanistan": 6545700,
        "categories": "2019"
    },
    {
        "Afghanistan": 7475886,
        "categories": "2020"
    },
    {
        "Albania": 740232,
        "categories": "2018"
    },
    {
        "Albania": 2374785,
        "categories": "2019"
    },
    {
        "Albania": 2180850,
        "categories": "2020"
    }
]
```

This was my expected output::

`[ { "Afghanistan": 2646432, "Albania": 740232, "categories": "2018" }, { "Afghanistan": 6545700, "Albania": 2374785, "categories": "2019" }, { "Afghanistan": 7475886, "Albania": 2180850, "categories": "2020" } ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const found = acc.find(obj => obj.categories === item.categories);
    if (found) {
        Object.assign(found, item);
    } else {
        acc.push(item);
    }
    return acc;
}, [])
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let list=[{Afghanistan:2646432,categories:"2018"},{Afghanistan:6545700,categories:"2019"},{Afghanistan:7475886,categories:"2020"},{Albania:740232,categories:"2018"},{Albania:2374785,categories:"2019"},{Albania:2180850,categories:"2020"},{India:2029282726,categories:"2022"},{India:2029282729,categories:"2023"},{Afghanistan:2029282729,categories:"2023"}];

let result = Object.values(list.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[cur.categories] ? acc[cur.categories] = {...acc[cur.categories], ...cur} : acc[cur.categories] = cur, acc), {}));

console.log(result);
```

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method